# Scipy Minimization and stepsize constraints

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, minimize, scipy-optimize

I use the `scipy.optimize.minimize` function and I have a 1D array as `x0` with different parameters inside it. Since I work with different physical parameters, I don't want, for example, to make an iteration of 0.1 for temperature of the order of magnitude of 2500K. So I want to put constraints on the function iterations for each inputs. I've tried this already :

```
x0 = [0.1, 10.0, 0.90,1200] #tau,star_diam,amC,Td
bounds = [ [0.005,1],[7,13],[0.05,1], [800,1500] ]

cons = []
for factor in range(len(bounds)):
    lower, upper = bounds[factor]
    l = {'type': 'ineq',
         'fun': lambda x, lb=lower, i=factor: x[i] - lb}
    u = {'type': 'ineq',
         'fun': lambda x, ub=upper, i=factor: ub - x[i]}
    cons.append(l)
    cons.append(u)


res = minimize(DUSTY_RUN,x0,args=(data_charac,lambda_max,lambda_min,DATA_DIR,INPUT_DIR), constraints=cons, method='COBYLA', options={'rhobeg': [0.01,0.01,0.01,100], 'maxiter': 5000, 'disp': False, 'catol': 1e-6})
```

In the options of the function, the `rhoberg` option is considered as `float`, I've tried to change it as a list/array but this didn't change anything as we may guess.

Comment: You can't force *some optimization path* in these *general NLP solvers*. You could *decompose* your approach though: an *outer* grid-search or similar + *inner NLP* for local-optimization / solution-polishing. Of course there is some information-loss and when evaluating grid-point x, you don't know anything about unevaluated grid-point y.

Comment: @sascha  Ok I was afraid about those kind of answer :/ Well thank you I will work on a grid approach first :)

Answer (score 0):

`rhoberg` is the initial step, so it doesn't directly control following steps. You can add scaling of parameters in your `DUSTY_RUN` function - since you wrote `[0.01,0.01,0.01,100]` you could multiply first three by `1e4`.