Scipy: optimisation with custom step
The task is to find the minimum of function with explicitly defined step.
I went through methods of scipy.optimize package, which use approximation approach (COBYLA, COBYQA), and didn't find any parameters and options, which can be used to pass the step size.
For example:
 initial_x_1 = np.float16([4.0])

 res_opt_x_1 = optimize.minimize(f_x_1, initial_x_1, method='COBYLA', options={'rhobeg': [2.0], 'maxiter': 50, 'disp': False, 'catol': 1e-4})

Is the other numeric methods in scipy.optimize, in which we can set the size of step explicitly?
Or, more generally, are there other numeric methods in OTHER Python mathematic libraries, in which we can set the size of step explicitly?

How's minimization supposed to use the custom step?  Normally it varies the initial value(s) a bit, calling your function.  Based on those results it chooses a new x, and repeats.

I use the Rozenbrock optimization algorythm. At each iteration I must apply one-dimentional optimization, considering   step, multiplied on changed orth: for example: x1 = x - step * e1,  where e1 - is rotated orth.  So I need to customize not so the step size, but to customize this part: "step * e1"

According to https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_cobyla.html, rhobeg specifies an initial (and maximum) change.  Apparently the purpose is to keep the interations from stepping outside of 'trust' region.  I couldn't tell from your question why you wanted to specify step.

To clarify - are you trying to set the step size of the numerical differentiation, or the step size during line search? The first one is much easier to control and much more likely to cause problems. (The line search step size is automatically reduced when steps are too big.)


Is the other numeric methods in scipy.optimize, in which we can set the size of step explicitly?

No, not out of the box. You'd have to control the step size at each iteration appropriately if you hope to converge.
But there are tools you can use to throw together a minimizer that allows you to set the step size at each iteration. For instance, a very easy to write, very bad gradient descent implementation:
from scipy.optimize import approx_fprime

def f(x):
    return (x - 1) @ (x - 1)

def df(x):
    return approx_fprime(x, f)

# custom step size rule
def step(i, x, fx, dfx):
    return 0.1 * np.linalg.norm(dfx)

def minimize(f, x0, step):
    x = x0
    for i in range(1000):
        fx = f(x)
        dfx = df(x)
        direction = dfx / np.linalg.norm(dfx)
        size = step(i, x, fx, dfx)
        x = x - size*direction
        if size < 1e-4:
            break

    return x, fx

x0 = np.asarray([1, 2])
minimize(f, x0, step)

# (array([0.99999999, 1.00032451]), 1.6454441346763623e-07)

I'd also suggest looking at scipy.optimize.line_search, scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar, and the source code of the various minimize methods for building blocks.

Or, more generally, are there other numeric methods in OTHER Python mathematic libraries, in which we can set the size of step explicitly?

I cannot answer this part. From https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic:

Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.


I this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61410292/scipy-minimization-and-stepsize-constraints. I have found, that rhobeg option set the initial step.

These methods:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-cg.html
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-bfgs.html

support finite_diff_rel_step to control the Jacobian step.
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-newtoncg.html supports eps to set the step size if the Hessian is approximated.
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-lbfgsb.html supports eps as the absolute step size again for the Jacobian.
And so on. So there are plenty of methods for which there is a "step size", but

the "step size" is ill-defined, and could mean a number of things in the context of a convex optimizer;
usually, you shouldn't set it yourself, and if you really, really think that you need to, then this is likely an X/Y problem; and
the methods that do support a step size may or may not be available to you depending on the nature of your cost function, which you haven't shown.


Those are step sizes for finite difference approximation of the Jacobian/Hessian. IIUC, the OP was asking for the steps to be taken from the guess (hopefully) toward the minimum. I agree with 1, 2, and 3, though.
